# Ionic: can you use navCtl.push() inside a provider

Tags: ionic-framework, navigation

I have setup a provider with a function that checks a value in storage and if not set will force the user to set it before using the app.

So, on every page, in the constructor I call my checkToken() function in the provider and if not set I want to do

```
this.navCtl.push(TokenPage)
```

But I get this error

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError[NavController]: 
  StaticInjectorError[NavController]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for NavController!
```

Here is the constructor in my provider

```
constructor(private inAppBrowser: InAppBrowser, private storage:Storage, private navCtl:NavController) {
    console.log('Hello SharedProvider Provider');
    this.live = false;

  }
```

and here is the function that checks for a value in my storage.

```
 checkLogin(){
    var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
      this.storage.get("virtualToken").then((val)=>{
        this.virtualToken = val;

      });
      this.storage.get("liveToken").then((val)=>{
        this.liveToken = val;
      });

    });
    if((this.virtualToken == null || this.virtualToken == '') && (this.liveToken == null || this.liveToken == '')){
      console.log("Result of checkLogin" + this.virtualToken);
      this.navCtl.push(TokenPage);
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be because NavController is not included in Ionic core module and hence it is not available in services/providers.
You can try this workaround but it is not ideal even i am using this in my provider to get access to navcontroller:-

```
constructor(protected app: App) {...
....
}

get navCtrl(): NavController {
    return this.app.getRootNav();
}
```

and then you could access the navCtrl anywhere in your service:

```
this.navCtl.push(TokenPage);
```